# How do I raise the humidity levels in my home?

Tags: humidity, air-quality, humidifier

I installed hardwood flooring in my home late last fall. The humidity level in my home this winter dropped incredibly low (20%). I'm not sure if it's related to the new hardwood.

I installed a whole home humidifier but it can't seem to bring the humidity levels above 30%.

It only runs when the furnace is running. Soon after the furnace shuts off, the humidity levels start dropping again.

How can I get the humidity level to rise to 40-50%, then maintain?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, new hardwood may indeed be absorbing some moisture, but 20% is not necessarily "incredibly low". That's normal, depending on your climate. In my region, 40% would have the windows dripping and frosted over in February. I imagine the same is true in Ottawa, Canada.

Here's a typical chart showing ideal conditions based on outdoor temperatures. Charts vary by 5-10%, but this gives you a general idea.

[image]

<sub>[source](https://www.buildingsciencesllc.com/blog/wintertime-indoor-humidity-levels) (not an endorsement)</sub>